# Detecting frequency when frequency is not sufficiently greater than baud rate

Tags: frequency, fsk

I'm writing software a Signal Analyzer, as in [Github - Signal Analyzer](https://github.com/dandandrea/SignalAnalyzer), for decoding audio samples of FSK data back to bits (ASCII, etc). The software is working really well at this point for decoding FSK when the mark and space frequencies are sufficiently greater than the baud rate.

However, I detect a frequency of $0\textrm{ Hz}$ when the mark and space frequencies are decreased to values which are not sufficiently greater than the baud rate. I've been using a pretty basic zero crossing algorithm for detecting the frequency present in a given interval. I gather that this is because the frequency is not great enough to have any zero crossings during the interval that I sample.

- What are some other methods for detecting whether the mark or space frequency are present in a given interval when the baud rate is not sufficiently greater than said frequencies?
- And as a follow-on question, is it common for the mark and space frequencies to not be sufficiently greater than the baud rate in real-life FSK implementations?

For example, I read in [Wikipedia - Bell 202 Modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_202_modem) that the mark and space frequencies for Bell 202 (1,200 baud) are $1200\textrm{ Hz}$ and and $2200\textrm{ Hz}$, respectively -- the algorithm I'm currently using can detect the $2200\textrm{ Hz}$ frequency but not the $1200\textrm{ Hz}$ frequency.

Comment: Well this classical FSK isn't used that often anymore; basically because it's not *that* easy to implement in software, and more importantly, not easier to implement than something spectrally more efficient. So "is this common" is a pretty relative term – but yes, there are quite a few systems that do that. The other day I learned about a class of aircraft transponders, for example.

Comment: What I can't really read from your question, though: does your system already know what the different subcarriers will be, or is this part of what's to estimate?

Comment: also, have a look at https://grinspector.wordpress.com/

Comment: "... when the mark and space frequencies are sufficiently lower than the baud rate". This would mean that only a fraction of a period of a sine falls inside a symbol interval. Usually you want at least one whole period of a sine in the symbol interval, i.e. the *smaller* of the two frequencies would be $f_1=1/T$, where $T$ is the symbol period.

Comment: @MarcusMüller at this point yes, the mark and space frequencies are known and have been provided to the software, as well as the baud rate

Comment: @MattL. That's what I'm concerned with. How does one detect the frequency when you have such a small sample of it (possibly less than one period)? I was brainstorming and the only thing that I could come up with was making taking the derivative at different points on the sample and trying to use the rate of change of the sine wave to extrapolate the frequency.

Comment: @Dan: But when the tone frequencies are equal to or greater than the baud rate, you do have one or more periods per symbol time. Why would you want to choose tone frequencies lower than the baud rate?

Comment: @MattL. You are totally right and I just realized that I worded my question incorrectly. I have edited the question to reflect the correct situation.

Comment: @MattL. actually, there was a discussion on implementing a receiver for exactly such a system, where the symbol duration was shorter than the mark/space frequency's period. It's a terrible system, from a lot of perspectives, but it seems to be a standard for a specific type of aircraft transponder. You can still build a system. I had to wrap my head around it, too, at first, but then I realized that the designers were probably thinking of superhet receivers with the IF lower than *both* mark and space, not in the center between them (like an SDR guy like me would put it).

Comment: @MattL. system name was UAT,  Universal Access Transceiver. It seems to use do ~1MS/s with $\Delta f = f_c + 312.5 \text{ kHz} - (f_c-312.5 \text{ kHz})=625 \text{ kHz}$, which means one symbol less than one third of a symbol frequency period, *if you mix $f_c$ to baseband*.

Comment: @Dan: if you read this above, the takeaway is the following: you don't actually "gain" any information, but think about what happens if you shift your mark/space frequencies in baseband by multiplying the whole signal with a $e^{j2\pi f_\text{offset}}$ so that they are no longer centered around 0, but have a much higher frequency – that way, you potentially get more than one period of mark/space frequency per symbol duration.

Comment: Since that doesn't add any energy to these signal, you don't gain any confidence over what you'd observe by simply correlating with the original signal with the carriers. However, it can make it much easier to discern the two tones e.g. with a DFT.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Thanks for the info! Hadn't heard of such a system.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That is a very interesting idea. I will try that out. I am currently working on a method based on derivation:

$frequency = (sampling rate / (2 * pi)) * rms(derivative) / rms(signal)$

Comment: @MattL. me neither. I was really confused when someone asked about help implementing a receiver for that... there's so much unnecessarily uncomfortable about it that Occam's Razor said the guy had misunderstood something. Note that they still restrict the overall system's bandwidth to little more than half the symbol rate – I am really in awe. It's the only system that I knew that would take sub-symbolrate frequency spacing and still critically restrict bandwidth.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I've got the following algorithm working but the tolerances are pretty loose (detects within +/- 200 Hz of the actual frequency).

Please see [this link](https://github.com/dandandrea/SignalAnalyzer/blob/master/Core/BinaryFskAnalysis/DerivativeFrequencyDetector.cs).

I think I'm going to start to look into the scaling idea you mentioned earlier.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I'm very interested in your suggestion about increasing the frequency of my samples to a rate at which I can accurately measure. Could you possibly provide me with a concrete example of how to do this? Do you perhaps know of a C# library that could help with this? My math is not entirely up to snuff for implementing some of the suggestions.

Comment: simply multiply each complex sample with $e^{j2\pi\frac{f_\text{shift}}{f_\text{sample}}}n$, with $n$ being the sample number.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Thanks, Marcus. My samples are currently shorts so I'l need to look into how to convert them to the complex domain. I'll work on implementing this tonight and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Dan technically, you want to generate the so-called *analytic signal* to your real-valued signal, probably. But: if those are short values, they are real, right? at which frequencies is mark & space right now?

Comment: err, just read it, 1.2 kHz and 2.2 kHz. Multiplication with a simple sine might work here, too, if you take care that the spectral duplicates you get that way don't end up in a place you care about.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41411/discussion-on-question-by-dan-detecting-frequency-when-frequency-is-not-sufficie).

Answer (score 2):

You should read [Wikipedia - Minimum Shift Keying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-shift_keying).  The minimum frequency distance between two FSK tones is half the baud rate.  But even at 1X the baud rate, the tones look blurred together in the spectrum.  Note that, without any pulse shaping, the bandwidth of each tone is effectively the baud rate.  This is related to the implicit rectangular window that is applied by the digital modulation.  So you have two tones that each have a width of the baud rate.  When the separation between them is the baud rate, the left sided half bandwidth of the high tone combines with the right-sided bandwidth of the low tone and you get one big blob.  If you were to pulse shape the signal in the phase domain, the single-tone bandwidth would be reduced and you would get more visual separation between the tones.

Demodulation for MSK is usually done in the phase domain, not the frequency domain for this reason.  If you plot the unwrapped phase of the signal you would see the phase sloping up for the high tone and sloping down for the low tone (assuming you're using a complex analytical form of the signal). You can demodulate the signal in the phase domain by using a filtered differentiator on the phase of the baseband signal which is basically an FM demod which turns an FSK signal into a BPSK signal.  You can also use a Phase locked loop (which is another form of FM demod).